# MS Access Search Form not returning records if one field in the WHERE statement is blank

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am struggling with a SQL query in MS Access.  I have a search screen created to look up records but if any of the fields I am searching in a record are blank then the record is skipped.  I have tried the OR statements testing for NULL but with the field from the form and what is in the table I am querying.  When I put that criteria in then I get everything and not just the records I am searching for.

MY SQL STATEMENT

```sql
SELECT TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Date_Live, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Date_Billing, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Date_Complete, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Date_Contract_Case, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.[PRJ_Case#], TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.[PRJ_Contract#], TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.[PRJ_Project#], TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Core_Type, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Core_DC, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Core_Loc, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.[PRJ_Core_Bnk#], TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_Cust_ID, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_Name, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_Name_Alt, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_City, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_ST, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_Assets, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Mgmt, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Project, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Meeting, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Prep, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Training, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Research, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Test, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_BA_Live, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_PGM_Live, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Support, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Misc, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_INS_Total, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Total, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Team, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Primary_BA, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Secondary_BA, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Primary_PGMR, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Secondary_PGMR, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Add_Resrc_1, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Add_Resrc_2, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Add_Resrc_3, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.CORE_Proj, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.CORE_PM, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.CORE_ASM, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.COMP_PM1, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.COMP_PM2, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Proj_Type, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Proj_Sub_Type, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Description, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.MGMT_Notes, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.MGMT_Desc_Of_Work, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HII_OLIP, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_OneNote, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_FSCM, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Planner, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_000000_Pot_Earn, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Book_Revenue, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Book_Rev_Comp, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_OneNote_Link, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Planner_Link, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.MGMT_Hold, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Custom, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Cancelled, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Cancel_DT, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Waiting_on_Cust, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HII_Waiting_On_ECS, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Closed_Mgmt, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_On_Backlog, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HII_ECS_Drop_Date, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_Development, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HRS_No_Chrg_Custom, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AUT_Ready, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Suite, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.ID, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_521000_IH_Install, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_521002_IH_Mrg, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_521005_OL_Disc, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_523000_CM_POD, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_524000_OL_Revenue, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_531000_Custom, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_531000_CSO, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_534000_Training, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_589606_Rev_xfer, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_799800_OL_Deferal, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_Bill_To, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Bill_To, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_Waive_Loss, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Waive_Loss_Reason, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Waive_Loss_Approver, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Status, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.AMT_000000_HII_Qtrly, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.HII_Hist_Retain, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.ID, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.REC_Date_Created, TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.REC_User_Created
FROM TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master

WHERE (((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Date_Live) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchLivDt] & "*") 
 
AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.[PRJ_Case#]) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchCase] & "*") 

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.[PRJ_Project#]) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchProjNum] & "*") 

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_Cust_ID) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchCmpID] & "*") 

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_Name) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchBnkNam] & "*") 

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_City) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchCity] & "*") 

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_ST) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchSt] & "*")

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Team) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchTeam] & "*") 

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Primary_BA) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchPrmRes] & "*") 

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Primary_PGMR) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchPrmRes] & "*") 

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Proj_Type) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchPrjType] & "*")

AND ((TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Proj_Sub_Type) Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchPrjSubTyp] & "*"))
ORDER BY TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Date_Live DESC;
```

My expectation would be that when I search it gets me the information regardless of if a field that is part of the search is blank in the record.  With my example above if I search for *TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.BNK_City*, but *TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Primary_PGMR* is blank. that record gets skipped.  I get all the other records for that city but not the one with a blank field.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try accepting *Null* values (you can leave out the table name), for example:

```
AND ([PRJ_Case#] Is Null Or [PRJ_Case#] Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchCase] & "*")
```

Comment: Nope added that code to the specific line and now i get every record where that field is blank even if its not part of the criteria

Comment: AND ([PRJ_Primary_PGMR] is Null OR [TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Primary_PGMR] Like "*" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchPrmPgm] & "*")

Comment: You can test ``[Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchPrmPgm]`` for null or empty :  ``AND ([Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchPrmPgm] is Null OR len([Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchPrmPgm])=0 OR  [TABLE_Project_Tracking_Master.PRJ_Primary_PGMR] Like "" & [Forms]![Copy Of 2200 - Manager Search]![SrchPrmPgm] & "") ``

Comment: ... _i get every record where that field is blank even if its not part of the criteria_ ... yes, you asked for _a field that is part of the search is blank in the record_.

Comment: Better explanation.  i search for a record with city but I won't see a matching record if one of the search fields is blank in the database.  i don't want to see all blanks but need them to come thru if the filter matches.

Comment: Actually, the solution proposed by ValNik is correct and should work.

Comment: ValNik's solution in a simpler form : (Nz([SearchText])="" OR [Field] Like "**" & [SearchText] & "**") . Also, you may consider using a parametric query and pass the values to it in your search form. Or create a dynamic query based on only non-empty search texts. The asterisks are omitted by the editor!